# Disable Minimize and Maximize Button in kivy application

Tags: python, kivy

1. I want to disable the minimize and maximize button in the kivy application

2)I have seen that we can set the minimum size for the window using below commmand.

```
Window.size = (800, 600)
Window.minimum_width, Window.minimum_height = Window.size
Window.maximum_width, Window.maximum_height = Window.size
```

I want to set a fixable size for the window. how to do that in kivy?

Comment: what you mean  fixable size for the window

Comment: I want the window size to be (800,600). resizing should not be possible for this window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `kivy.config.Config` to do what you want. Just place these three lines at the very top of your main python script:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', 1)
```

See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.config.html#available-configuration-tokens).

Answer (score 2):

1. to set the kivy button to be fixed size you need to disable the relative size and set fixed one like this

```py
Button:
    size_hint:None,None
    size:dp(200),dp(100)
```

or in python code

```py
Button(size_hint=(None,None),size=(dp(200),dp(100)))
```

2. to set fixable window size first you need to set the window size

```py
Window.size = (800, 600)
```

and disable the resizing to the window from the user by adding this to the top of your python code

```py
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
```

Comment: it is not working for me. for setting as you mentioned. still i can see that my screen is getting resized.

Comment: are you in using windows ?

Comment: did you put this `from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)` code in the the top of the python file

Comment: earlier i did not kept at top. now it works after kept at top. Thanks Hussam F. Alkdary